# MediaPlayer NullPointerException on Android TV , Version 9

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I am continuously getting Crash report from Android TV version 9, It's  difficult for me to troubleshoot this because I'm getting this via a crash report from someone else's android tv, It is working fine in all other devices where I tested.
Also I didn't where for which scree or which code is crashing. It stated the MediaPlayer file which is android's own code.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:3533)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6670)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:0)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Below is the code for my splashscreen where this crash came when started the app

```
    private static final String TAG = "SplashScreen ";
    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private boolean finishActivity;
    private VideoViewCustom videoView;
    private int playVideoFlag = 0;
    private CheckNetwork chNetwork;
    private Context context;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private String partnerPath = "";
    private PermissionInterface permissionInterface;
    private Activity activity;
    final public static int APN_SETTINGS = 101;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    String folder = "";
    int codeLoginClass = 3;
    int codeLoginStudent = 15;
    int codeLoginTeacher = 14;
    int setCode;
    TrackingDbHelper trackDbHelper;
    private MyCLTPathReceiver reMyCltPathReceiver;
    private MyCLTVIdeoPathReciver myCLTVideoReceiver;
    private IntentFilter filter;
    private IntentFilter filter1;
    String pathOfCLT = "";
    String pathOfCLTVideo = "";
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final int delay = 15000; 
    private Runnable runnable;

    List<String> DBPaths = new ArrayList<String>();
    String Path1 = "/CLT.sqlite";
    String Path2 = "/Master.sqlite";

    private double locationRequestLatitude = 0.0;
    private double locationRequestLongitude = 0.0;
    private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
    private FirebaseCrashlytics firebaseCrashlytics;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        firebaseCrashlytics = FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance();

        setCode = codeLoginClass;
        context = this;
        activity = this;
        permissionInterface = SplashScreen.this;
        videoView = (VideoViewCustom) findViewById(R.id.videoClip);
        chNetwork = new CheckNetwork(this);
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(SplashScreen.this);
        trackDbHelper = new TrackingDbHelper(this);


        pref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.code), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        reMyCltPathReceiver = new SplashScreen.MyCLTPathReceiver();
        myCLTVideoReceiver = new SplashScreen.MyCLTVIdeoPathReciver();
        filter = new IntentFilter("CLTPATH");
        filter1 = new IntentFilter("CLTVIDEOPATH");
        checkPermissions();
    }


    @SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
    public void displaySplashScreen() {
        VideoUtils.writeToFile("CLT_Classroom_Logs.txt", "\n  displaySplashScreen()" );
        CheckDateNChange checkDateNChange = new CheckDateNChange(this);
        checkDateNChange.setTime();
        if ("".equals(preferences.getString(Constants.PREFS_CLT_VIDEOS_PATH, ""))) {
            Log.d("VIDLocation","0 path ");
            new CLTVideosPath(getApplicationContext(), SplashScreen.this, false).execute(" ");
        }
        if ("".equals(preferences.getString(Constants.PREFS_CLT_PATH, ""))) {
            new CLTPath(context, SplashScreen.this, false).execute(" ");

        }
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return ;
        }
        String imei;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            imei = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        }else {

            if (tm.getDeviceId() != null) {
                imei = tm.getDeviceId();
            } else {
                imei = Settings.Secure.getString(
                        context.getContentResolver(),
                        Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"Android ID: " + Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID));
        Log.d(TAG,"IMEI ID: " + imei);
        SetPreference.setDeviceImeiId(SplashScreen.this, Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID), imei);

        if (getIntent() != null) {
            finishActivity = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(Constants.FINISH_ACTIVITY, false);
            playVideoFlag = getIntent().getIntExtra(Constants.PLAY_VIDEO, 0);
            Logger.logD("playVideo", "playVideo--" + playVideoFlag);
        }
        checkNcallLoginTask();
        Logger.logD("finishActivity", "finishActivity--" + finishActivity);
        Utilities.appVersionAtBottomOfScreen(this, this, pref.getString(Constants.ANDROID_DEVICE_ID, ""));

       finishOrlaunch();
    }

    private void finishOrlaunch() {
        if (finishActivity)
            finish();
        if (pref.getBoolean(PrefUtils.USER_LOGIN, false)) {
            appLaunchedNew();
            displayVideo();

        } else {
            playVideo();
        }
    }

    private void checkNcallLoginTask() {
        try {
            MinAppVAPI.getMinAppVersion(this, Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), "android_id"), this);
            if (chNetwork.checkNetwork() && !"".equals(pref.getString("ValiedLicence", ""))) {

                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                Logger.logD(TAG, "Current time => " + c.getTime());

                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                String str1 = df.format(c.getTime());
                Date date1 = formatter.parse(str1);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("DBValue", 2);
                editor.apply();
                String str2 = pref.getString("ValiedLicence", "");
                Date date2 = formatter.parse(str2);
                if (date1.compareTo(date2) < 0 && pref.getBoolean("loginCall", true)) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editors = preferences.edit();
                    editors.putBoolean("LicenseCheck", true);
                    editors.apply();
                    org.mahiti.clt.survey.utils.Logger.logV(TAG, "the current date is" + date1);
                    org.mahiti.clt.survey.utils.Logger.logV(TAG, "the current date is" + date2);
                    org.mahiti.clt.survey.utils.Logger.logV(TAG, "the logincall date is" + pref.getBoolean("loginCall", true));
                    new LoginAsyncTask(SplashScreen.this, SplashScreen.this, SplashScreen.this).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                } else {
                    Logger.logV(TAG, "the licence already called");
                }
            } else {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("DBValue", 1);
                editor.apply();
                new LoginAsyncTask(SplashScreen.this, SplashScreen.this, SplashScreen.this).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

            }
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            Logger.logE(TAG, "the error in splash is", e1);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void partnerPage(String path) {
        partnerPath = path;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(Constants.PREFS_PARTNER, partnerPath);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void checkPermissions() {
        if (!PermissionClass.checkPermission(this)) {
            PermissionClass.requestPermission(this, permissionInterface);
            Logger.logD("Permission Granted", "Permission Granted");
        }else{
            displaySplashScreen();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean granted(boolean value) {
        if (value) {
            Logger.logV(TAG, "the retured value is........" + value);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("Grant", true);
            editor.apply();
            displaySplashScreen();
        }
        return false;
    }



    public void appLaunched() {
        TrackingDbHelper helper = new TrackingDbHelper(this);
        LaunchApp tracker = new LaunchApp();
        TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String imei = "";
        if (mTelephonyMgr == null || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            imei = mTelephonyMgr.getDeviceId(0);
        }
        tracker.setDeviceId(pref.getString(Constants.ANDROID_DEVICE_ID, ""));
        tracker.setImei(imei);
        GetLocations getLocations = new GetLocations(this, false);
        tracker.setLatitude(getLocations.getLat());
        tracker.setLongitude(getLocations.getLon());
        Log.d(TAG, "appLaunched: Latitude");
        tracker.setLaunchTime(CalendarUtils.getCurrentDate());
        tracker.setCloseTime("0");
        long id = helper.insertAppLaunchTracker(tracker);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putLong(PrefUtils.PREFAPPLAUNCHID, id);
        editor.apply();
    }

    @SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
    public void appLaunchedNew() {

        TrackingDbHelper helper = new TrackingDbHelper(this);
        LaunchApp tracker = new LaunchApp();

        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return ;
        }
        String imei;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            imei = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        }else {

            if (tm.getDeviceId() != null) {
                imei = tm.getDeviceId();
            } else {
                imei = Settings.Secure.getString(
                        context.getContentResolver(),
                        Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            }
        }

        tracker.setDeviceId(pref.getString(Constants.ANDROID_DEVICE_ID, ""));
        tracker.setImei(imei);
        GetLocations getLocations = new GetLocations(this, false);
        tracker.setLatitude(getLocations.getLat());
        tracker.setLongitude(getLocations.getLon());
        Log.d(TAG, "appLaunchedNew: Latitude  "+getLocations.getLat());
        Log.d(TAG, "appLaunchedNew: Longitude "+getLocations.getLon());
        getCurrentLocation();

        tracker.setLaunchTime(CalendarUtils.getCurrentDate());
        tracker.setCloseTime("0");
        long id = helper.insertAppLaunchTracker(tracker);

        AnalyticsDbHelper analyticsDbHelper = new AnalyticsDbHelper(this);
        Log.d(TAG, "appLaunchedNew: LaunchTime "+tracker.getLaunchTime());
        Log.d(TAG, "appLaunchedNew: Imei "+tracker.getImei());
        analyticsDbHelper.setSPLaunchTime(this, tracker.getLaunchTime());
        analyticsDbHelper.setSPImei(this, tracker.getImei());

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putLong(PrefUtils.PREFAPPLAUNCHID, id);
        editor.apply();

    }

    private void getCurrentLocation() {

        final LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        Log.d(TAG, "getCurrentLocation: 01");

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getCurrentLocation: Inside If");
            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "getCurrentLocation: 02");
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this).requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                Log.d(TAG, "getCurrentLocation: Inside Result "+locationResult);
                LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getApplicationContext()).removeLocationUpdates(this);
                if (locationResult != null && locationResult.getLocations().size() > 0) {
                    int latestLocationIndex = locationResult.getLocations().size() - 1;
                    double latitude = locationResult.getLocations().get(latestLocationIndex).getLatitude();
                    double longitude = locationResult.getLocations().get(latestLocationIndex).getLongitude();
                    Log.d(TAG, "getCurrentLocation: Latitude  "+latitude);
                    Log.d(TAG, "getCurrentLocation: Longitude "+longitude);
                }
            }
        }, Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    private void checkLocationPermission() {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
        }
        else {
            getCurrentLocation();
        }

    }



    public void displayVideo() {
        try {
            String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.final_logo_animation;
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
            MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this, false);
            mediaController.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams rlParams = videoView.getLayoutParams();
            DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

            videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
            videoView.setDimensions(displaymetrics.widthPixels,rlParams.height);
            videoView.getHolder().setFixedSize(displaymetrics.widthPixels,rlParams.height);

            videoView.requestFocus();
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer media) {
                    media.start();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.logE(Constants.PROJECT, "video play-", e);
        }
        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                launchMainScreen();
            }
        });

        videoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                if(what==100){
                    try {
                        String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.final_logo_animation;
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
                        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(SplashScreen.this, false);
                        mediaController.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams rlParams = videoView.getLayoutParams();
                        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

                        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
                        videoView.setDimensions(displaymetrics.widthPixels,rlParams.height);
                        videoView.getHolder().setFixedSize(displaymetrics.widthPixels,rlParams.height);
                        if (videoView!=null) {
                            videoView.start();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Logger.logE(Constants.PROJECT, "video play-", e);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    private void launchMainScreen() {
        VideoUtils.writeToFile("CLT_Classroom_Logs.txt", "\n SplashScreen - LaunchmainScreen"  );
        DBDownloadSync();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case APN_SETTINGS:
                checkAPNSettings(grantResults);
                break;
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    org.mahiti.clt.utils.Logger.logD(TAG, "Permission granted!");
                    displaySplashScreen();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    private void checkAPNSettings(int[] grantResults) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                checkAndroidVersion();
            } else {
                org.mahiti.clt.utils.Logger.logD(TAG, "SEND_SMS Denied");
            }
        }
    }

    public void checkAndroidVersion() {
        int checkCallPhonePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, WRITE_APN_SETTINGS);
        if (checkCallPhonePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{WRITE_APN_SETTINGS}, APN_SETTINGS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (pref.getBoolean(PrefUtils.PREFBACKFLOW, false)) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean(PrefUtils.PREFBACKFLOW, false);
            editor.apply();
            finish();
        }
        registerReceiver(reMyCltPathReceiver, filter);
        registerReceiver(myCLTVideoReceiver, filter1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        TrackingDbHelper helper = new TrackingDbHelper(this);
        helper.updateLaunchTracker(pref.getLong(PrefUtils.PREFAPPLAUNCHID, 0), CalendarUtils.getCurrentDate());
        CallLogOut.callIntentSign(trackDbHelper, pref, setCode, this);
        finish();

    }



    public class MyCLTPathReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            pathOfCLT = preferences.getString(Constants.PREFS_CLT_PATH, "");
        }
    }

    public class MyCLTVIdeoPathReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            pathOfCLTVideo = preferences.getString(Constants.PREFS_CLT_VIDEOS_PATH, "");

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(reMyCltPathReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(myCLTVideoReceiver);
    }

    public void goTOLogin(String loginMode) {
        LoginCheck.loginCheck(this, setCode, 2);
        VideoUtils.writeToFile("CLT_Classroom_Logs.txt", "\n splashscreen gotToLogin mode : "+loginMode  );
        if ("".equals(pref.getString("subjects", ""))) {
            ToastUtils.displayToast("Please check the network to continue the application,get the license and proceed", this);
            return;
        }
        switch (loginMode) {
            case "classRoom":
                pref.edit().putInt(Constants.PREFS_LOGIN_MODE, 1).apply();
                pref.edit().putLong(PrefUtils.PREFUSERID, codeLoginClass).apply();
                break;
            case "teacher":
                pref.edit().putInt(Constants.PREFS_LOGIN_MODE, 2).apply();
                pref.edit().putLong(PrefUtils.PREFUSERID, codeLoginTeacher).apply();
                break;
            case "student":
                pref.edit().putInt(Constants.PREFS_LOGIN_MODE, 3).apply();
                pref.edit().putLong(PrefUtils.PREFUSERID, codeLoginStudent).apply();
                break;
            default:
                break;


        }
            if ("".equals(preferences.getString(Constants.PREFS_PARTNER, ""))) {
                appLaunchedNew();
                VideoUtils.writeToFile("CLT_Classroom_Logs.txt", "\n Moving to LangActivity"  );
                Intent i = new Intent(this, LanguageActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("mode", loginMode);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            } else {
                partnerPath = preferences.getString(Constants.PREFS_PARTNER, "");
                VideoUtils.writeToFile("CLT_Classroom_Logs.txt", "\n Moving to PartnerActivity "  );
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, PartnerActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("path", partnerPath);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
    }


    private void playVideo() {
        Logger.logD(TAG, "playVideo()--" + playVideoFlag);
        if (playVideoFlag == 1)
            launchMainScreen();
        else if (playVideoFlag == 0)
            displayVideo();
    }

    @Override
    public void minAppVToUpdate(String response) {
        Logger.logD(TAG, " min app v response in splash-xscreen :"+response);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCopyDatabaseComplete(boolean isDbCopyCompleted, String message) {
        if (isDbCopyCompleted)
            goTOLogin("classRoom");
        else
            showAlert(message);
    }

    private boolean  showAlert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(message);
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        activity.finish();

                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
        return false;
    }

    private void DBDownloadSync(){
        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences(this.getString(R.string.code), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String path_new = "";
        String VPathNew = preferences.getString(Constants.PREFS_CLT_VIDEOS_PATH_NEW, "");
        String VPathOld = preferences.getString(Constants.PREFS_CLT_VIDEOS_PATH, "");
        Log.d(TAG, "V NEW PATH " + VPathNew);
        int flagId = 0;
        if (VPathNew.equals("")){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            File[] listExternalDirs = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this, null);
            if (listExternalDirs.length > 1){
                if (listExternalDirs[0].getAbsolutePath().toLowerCase().contains("/storage/emulated/0")){
                    path_new = listExternalDirs[1].getAbsolutePath();
                    flagId = 1;
                } else{
                    path_new = listExternalDirs[0].getAbsolutePath();
                    flagId = 2;
                }
            } else {
                if (!VPathOld.equals("")) {
                    path_new = VPathOld.replace("/CLTVIDEOS", "") + "/Android/data/org.mahiti.clt/files";
                    flagId = 3;
                } else {
                    path_new = listExternalDirs[0].getAbsolutePath();
                    flagId = 4;
                }
            }
            path_new = path_new + "/CLTVIDEOS";
            Log.d(TAG, "NEW PATH 0 " + path_new + " " + flagId);
            editor.putString(Constants.PREFS_CLT_VIDEOS_PATH_NEW, path_new);
            Log.d("VIDLocation","4 path " + path_new);
            editor.apply();
        } else {
            path_new = VPathNew;
            Log.d(TAG, "NEW PATH " + path_new + " 5");
        }


        File DBSavingPath1 = new File(path_new + Path1);
        File DBSavingPath2 = new File(path_new + Path2);
        if (!DBSavingPath1.exists()){
            Log.d(TAG, "DB PATH1");
            DBPaths.add(Path1);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "DB PATH1 EXISTS");
        }
        if (!DBSavingPath2.exists()){
            Log.d(TAG, "DB PATH2");
            DBPaths.add(Path2);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "DB PATH2 EXISTS");
        }
        if (DBPaths.size() > 0){
            CheckNetwork chNetwork = new CheckNetwork(this);
            if (chNetwork.checkNetwork())
                new VideoDownloadAsyncTask(this, Constants.DBMAINURL, preferences, DBPaths).execute();
            else
                new CopyDBFilesAsyncTask(preferences, folder, this, SplashScreen.this, 1).execute();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "DB else");
            new CopyDBFilesAsyncTask(preferences, folder, this, SplashScreen.this, 2).execute(); 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void callback(String str, int val) {
        Log.d(TAG, "DB callback");
        new CopyDBFilesAsyncTask(preferences, folder, this, SplashScreen.this, 2).execute(); 

    }
}
```

Comment: If you add the code of that exception then anything can be possible to guess.

Comment: I edited the question and added my code